# How to call a typescript method from gulpfile.js

Tags: typescript, gulp

I have a project where my `gulpfile.js` is reasonably complex and so I want to factor out some of the code into `typescript`.

How do I call the typescript code from gulpfile.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can have a look how the dev team behind typescript itself have done it:

1. Here is [gulpfile.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/Gulpfile.ts) - its in typescript - perfect!
2. Here is [package.json](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/package.json) - note the usage of [ts-node](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node) - this is a key to the solution.

And that is basically it.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably easier to go with [gulpclass](https://github.com/pleerock/gulpclass) from the start but this is how I wrangled it:

**config.ts**

```
export function getString() : string
{  
    return "getString() worked!";
}

class Animal{
    legs : number = 4;
    Sound():string{return "Woof!"}
}

export var dog = new Animal();
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/*.spec.ts"
    ],
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "outDir" :"./src",
    }
}
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp')
var config = require("./src/config.js");

gulp.task('default', function () {
    console.log(config.getString());
    console.log(config.dog.Sound());
    console.log(config.dog.legs);
});
```

**Output**

```
[21:03:43] Starting 'default'...
getString() worked!
Woof!
4
```

**Notes**

- `commonjs` module setting was a key
- The gulp file was compiling the *.ts (not shown here) which meant the current gulp was always loading one version of tsc too old. [gulpclass](https://github.com/pleerock/gulpclass) perhaps does it better with the transpile syntax